# Uninstall Ubuntu 14.10 from Windows 8.1 computer

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, 14.10

I want to completely uninstall ubuntu 14.10 from my system.But I run it alongside windows 8.1,so I cant just format the drive.Also,will I be able to login into windows once ubuntu is uninstalled because grub may create problems once ubuntu is uninstalled and I fear I wont get an option to login into windows.

Answer (score 0):

Computers that ship with Windows 8 or later are different from previous ones. They can completely leverage UEFI and won't have bootloader in MBR overwriting each other. Instead, they have an EFI System Partition where bootloaders all have their own directory.

Check is you have such an installation, which you can check by running the following command:

```
$ mount | grep efi
```

Which should give you output similar to this:

```
none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)
```

Then you can just delete the Ubuntu partition, without having to worry.

#### Related:

- [How do I remove "Ubuntu" in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](https://askubuntu.com/q/63610/40581)

Answer (score -1):

Login to the Ubuntu then click on restart this will take you to the "advanced option of Ubuntu" in this page select the option windows (loader) (on /dev/sda1) which will be last option. This will help to boot to  windows. After login to the windows Right click on the computer---->Manage---->Disk Management.

After selecting the Disk Management identify the Ubuntu partition then right click on the Ubuntu partition and delete the volume. After doing this create a new volume and restart the computer. Once the machine restarted Press Enter key--->Next--->Repair your computer---->troubleshooting---->Advanced options--->command prompt

In the command prompt type as

bootrec.exe  /fixmbr

You will receive message as operation completed successfully. Close the command prompt and click on continue. This will help to uninstall Ubuntu without any affect to windows.